# UITableViewRowAction adjust dimensions (height)

Tags: swift

so i have a table in which I have made a little "hack" so to say. The "hack" was to create a `UIView` with a color and a smaller height than the actual (now transparent) cell, to make it look like there was spacing between all the cells.

My issue is now, that there is a 10 units gap from the "imaginary" cell to the actual buttom of the cell. Meaning that when i add my `UITableViewRowAction`, it will look like this:

[image: UITableViewRowAction too high]

Obviously i want it to have the same height.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let more = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "More") { action, index in
        print("more button tapped")
    }
    more.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    return [more]
}
```

This is what i have now.. but really i have no clue as to how i would adjust the height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit I misread the question.  What you really need to know is do you provide a custom view for the editing actions for your tableViewCell.  There is a detailed tutorial for this here: https://www.raywenderlich.com/62435/make-swipeable-table-view-cell-actions-without-going-nuts-scroll-views

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However i dont want my UIView to fill the entire cell. I want my Actions to have a smaller height. Are you sure we talk about the same? :-)

Comment: You are correct I misread your question.  I have corrected the answer and I hope its helpful.